# .PHP email form sends but empty fields are received

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, email

I have made a .PHP file that when the email form is filled out it sends it to my email address. Now this all works fine, I get the email, but, I get empty fields, here is the email I received from my test:

"Name:

Email:

Messages: "

as you see, all the fields are empty even though they were filled out.

Here is the code for the .php file:

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST['name'];
$email_message = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$headers = "Website message";
$headers = "From: $_email";
$to = 'enquiries@ajmoger.co.uk';
$subject = 'AJ Moger website comment submission';
$message = "
Name: $first_name \n
Email: $email_message \n
Messages: $message \n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header("Location: thank_you.html");
die();
?>'
```

and here is the HTML code for the form:

Comment: http://gyazo.com/7257d46ad25bd2ad8c8150219eaf3657 html code form

Comment: Your headers are getting overwritten.

Comment: Ok, so where should they go? straight after <?php  ?

Comment: You need to concatenate them. See example #4 on the PHP Manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-examples

Comment: Here are the steps in order: email sent:http://gyazo.com/9fd43829862b7e123d7a7c6ea910c0ac confirmation: http://gyazo.com/3edde63e5b51dc4cc3e10fba46d933c4 email received: http://gyazo.com/65f457697cd2050d4ad632f26f7f7bd0

Comment: **This is just for testing purpose:** Comment your `mail()` and put `var_dump($_POST);` on your PHP script and check if the variables are populating properly. I suspect your `<form>` code , You should post that too.

Comment: Ok i'll give that a go, the <form> code is the first comment up top.

Comment: I put in var_dump($_POST); and it came up with 'No data received' when the submit button was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is `enctype="text/plain"` on your `<form>`. Remove that from your `<form>` code.

There seems like a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33741) was filed on this topic , but the status is closed. So it's better not to use that encoding type.